# Get the byte array of a CoyoteOutputStream

Tags: java, outputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

How to get the binary stream out from CoyoteOutputStream?

```
OutputStream out = getOutputStream(); // returns a CoyoteOutputStream object         
out.write(binary);
out.flush();
```

Is there way to get the byte array back like in ByteArrayOutputStream toByteArray() ?

Thank You.

Comment: eh? Don't u have it already in the variable binary?

Comment: No, this isn't possible. The data is kept in a limited-size internal buffer that can get flushed before the response is finished.

Comment: well samuel lets say the binary data writing thing happen in a diferent service and in my side i get have only the CoyoteOutputStream object with its binary data written..

Comment: 9 years after and I also encounter the problem. @Harshana any answers?